# Substituting a function in the output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

I have to calculate the derivatives of the function `K` defined in the code:

```
<< VectorAnalysis`
K = δ[t]*Exp[-(r/L)]/r;
SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]];

r = Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2];
Hes = D[K, {{x, y, z}, 2}];
der = Grad[K];
FullSimplify[der[[1]]]
FullSimplify[Hes[[1, 2]]]
FullSimplify[Hes[[1, 1]]]
```

This is part the output just for `FullSimplify[der[[1]]]`:

> ```
> -((E^(-(Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2]/ L)) (x - x0) (L + 
>     Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2]) δ[t])/( L ((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + 
>   (z - z0)^2)^(3/2)))
> ```

I would like the function `K` to appear in the result instead of that "mess": is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your goal since you've expressed `K` and switched coordinates.

Maybe this could be what you're after?

```
Simplify[(der /. r^2 -> rad^2), rad > 0] /. E^(-(rad/L)) -> newK rad/δ[t]
```

> [image]

Comment: Yes it is. I thought it was more complicated... thank you!

Comment: @mattiav27 I'm glad you like it. It is good to hold on with an accept a day or two, there are better ways of workng with vector analisys and someone may provide an answer :) Let's do not discourage them :) You can still upvote this answer if you want.